Performance Issues with AWS Load Balancer and EC2 Instances Despite Scaling Up
I'm experiencing performance issues with my application running on AWS despite scaling up the number of EC2 instances. Here are the details of my setup and the problem I'm encountering:
Setup:

AWS Load Balancer: Application Load Balancer (ALB)
EC2 Instances: Initially 2 large instances, scaled up to 7 large instances
Database: AWS DocumentDB, instance type xlarge
Testing Tool: JMeter, simulating 520 threads each making 10 API calls per minute

Problem:
When testing with JMeter, the average response time per request is over 10 seconds, even after scaling up the number of EC2 instances. Here are the results:

Despite increasing the number of instances, the response times do not improve significantly and even degrade in some cases.
What I've Checked:

EC2 Instance Utilization: Instances are not maxing out CPU or memory.
Load Balancer Health Checks: Properly configured and all instances are healthy.
Sticky Sessions: Not using sticky sessions.
DocumentDB: Indexed properly and performing within expected parameters. I have also upgraded the DocumentDB instance to xlarge and used 2 replicas, but the results have not improved. The CPU and memory usage of DocumentDB appear to be completely healthy.

Question:
What could be causing these performance issues despite the increased number of EC2 instances? Are there specific areas or configurations in AWS that I might be overlooking? Any insights or suggestions for further investigation would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Info:

The application handles various API requests that interact with AWS
DocumentDB.
Using AWS CloudWatch for monitoring metrics.

Thank you in advance for your help!

You need to add some logging to your application to figure out where the time is being spent. At the very least, to identify whether or not it's a problem that can be solved with AWS configuration, log the start and end of each request. Better is to log the start and end of your controller methods, and key points within the methods. You could also use AWS XRay, but TBH getting some logging into your app will be faster and will have long-term benefits.

It might be the case you're hitting only one instance behind the load balancer due to JVM caching of DNS requests.
You need to either disable DNS caching or add DNS Cache Manager and use a custom DNS resolver so each virtual user would get the IP address behind the load balancer on its own.

As they’ve mentioned they are not using sticky sessions, so there is no way only one instance is getting hit. If there are multiple targets registered, load balancer will decide based on the algorithm.
